# What does the option "Auto share projects located in git repository" of EGit mean?

Tags: eclipse, git, maven, egit

Every time I import a maven project. Among the remaining tasks to be done always appears *Auto share git project (waiting)*.

I dig in the web and I just find where enable/disable the option, but I want to understand what is doing and if I need it.

What I always do is create/clone the project in command line and then import it in Eclipse, then I can do all the git work in EGit.

Is the *Auto share projects located in git repository* option necessary in this scenario or I can disable it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Short: Yes the option is necessary, otherwise you will have to manually share the project with the repository it belongs to.

The option *Auto share projects located in Git repository* usually saves you the extra step of *sharing* the created or imported project with a repository.

A project that belongs to a certain repository (in Git: is located within the work directory) needs to be marked as such. Therefore you would open the projects context menu, go to *Team > Share Project* and select the repository.

Only thereafter you will see decorations (e.g. current branch) and be able to commit changes of that project etc.

Whenever a project is created or imported that is located within the work directory of a repository known to EGit, it will be automatically be shared if the above option is enabled.

Comment: Since I always do m gt work on the CLI, is there any reason to keep this option turned on?

Comment: I'd say it depends on which parts of EGit you use.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge EGit just sits there and is 100% ignored by me. At most I glance at which branch is active, but I use CLI for switching branches, not EGit.

Comment: I'm asking this too late but what does "share the project with the repository it belongs to" mean? what are we sharing and why?

Comment: 'share project' here means to let EGit track the Git status of the given project in the Eclipse workspace, That is, decorate files as dirty, staged, etc. and let you run actions like checkout on that project. Unless you 'share'  a project, EGit won't recognize it. 'auto-share' observes the workspace and starts tracking a project as soon as it becomes part of the workspace. Does that answer your question?