# EGit not working after switching my workspace

Tags: eclipse, egit

I have recently switched to a new workspace and have been unable to get some of the EGit functionalities to run since.

For example, when I right click and choose "Compare with", I now only have "Revision" and "Local History" as options - the "Commit" option is gone. The same goes for right clicking "Replace with".

Clicking on "Team" after right-clicking no longer produces the "Show in History" option.

The annotations on the right, which show which line of code has been added by who, also no longer shows.

I am sure that there are some more functionalities that I have lost since changing my workspace, but these were the most common ones that I used.

Anyway, my question would be if anyone has any tips on what I need to do in order to get these options back. I've searched the Eclipse and EGit documentations and boards, but have not had much luck.

Comment: Do you see the project decorations in the Package/Project Explorer/Navigator, something like. `my-project [my-repo master ...]`?

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the repositories you are working with to make EGit aware of them. In the *Repositories* view, select the *Add existing repository* tool button from the top of the view and choose the repositories in which your projects are stored.

Afterwards, you may need to *Share* the projects with their respective repositories (see [What does the option "Auto share projects located in git repository" of EGit mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30897185/what-does-the-option-auto-share-projects-located-in-git-repository-of-egit-mea/33441449#33441449)). Then you should be set up again.